# onTouchStart override all the other components of Div in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm working on a [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) application in which I have a `div` tag where I have multiple buttons and their click event. When I'm adding onTouchStart event to call a method then it's overrides all the buttons click event.
Means after adding onTouchStart event, button click not working longer. Please guide me. Thanks in advance !!

```
<div ontouchstart="event.preventDefault();dismissPopUp()">
    <input type="button" class="save" value="Save" onclick="save();">
    <input type="button" class="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `onTouchStart` is the problem? IIRC Android does not allow for inline `onclick` functions. You should be using [unobtrusive javascript](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important) anyway

Comment: yes, thanks to all of your comments. onClick event work and call both div methods as well as button click methods.

Comment: @RiteshKumarSingh If you have found a solution, than please explain in detail how the question was solved by answering you own question. This would help others who come across your question.